# I can't get line returns in CodeIgniter plain text email messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, newline, codeigniter-2, email

I've been struggling with this one.  No matter what I do, I cannot get new lines, empty lines, or line returns to show up in any email message I generate with CodeIgniter (v 2.1.3).

Within my **Controller function**:

```
$message = "Line one.\r\n\r\n" .
"Line two.\r\n\r\n" .
"Line three.\r\n\r\n";

$subject = "My Subject Line";

$this->load->library('email');                  
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";  // does not matter when I leave this out
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";     // does not matter when I leave this out
$this->email->initialize($config);              
$this->email->from('system@mydomain.com', 'my system');
$this->email->to('me@gmail.com');               
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);                
$this->email->send();               
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I've changed no settings or defaults, other than what I've shown above.

The "source" of the message looks just like this `print_debugger()` output...

```
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 17:46:47 -0400
From: "my system" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "system@mydomain.com" 
X-Sender: system@mydomain.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <xxxxxx@mydomain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_514f74472bd26" 

=?utf-8?Q?My_Subject_Line?=
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_514f74472bd26
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Line one.

Line two.

Line three.

--B_ALT_514f74472bd26
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Line one.

Line two.

Line three.

--B_ALT_514f74472bd26--
```

**HOWEVER**, the problem is that the actual message is rendering in all email clients as the following.

```
Line one.Line two.Line three.
```

Why are my `"\r\n"` being ignored?

This is a very simple message and I'd prefer to not have to use any `html` options.  [As per CI documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), the `mailtype` preference should be defaulting to `text`.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>The CodeIgniter 2 documentation appears to be wrong.</s>

[On this page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), it contains a listing of available preferences.

Note this one, `mailtype`...

```
Preference     Default Value      Options       
mailtype       text               text or html
```

Adding the following setting fixed this problem, <s>so clearly it's not the "default value"...</s>

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
```

My thread at CI asking about this discrepancy in the docs:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/234296/

---

**EDIT**:

Entire problem was being caused by the following code within my Ion Auth configuration file...

```
$config['email_config'] = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me an hour of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems codigniter is sending your email as both text/html and text/plain. Most email clients render html version of emails and in html white spaces are broken down to a singe space. Check if codeigniter has an option to turn off sending an html version or just use `<br>` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: Originally, I started with some basic HTML (`<br>`, etc.) and I know that works. However, I cannot use HTML within this message or the spam score shoots through the roof.  I'll manually apply the `text` preference to see if it matters.  My OP is asking how to do it in plain text.